# MVC get variable from url (routing) in view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my routing I have

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ctrl",
    url: "ctrl/{target_name}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ctrl", action = "TheAction" }
);
```

How do I access target_name? I tried ViewBag.target_name, I Googled and found many pages say `RouteData.Values` but I get a compile error

```
CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Routing.RouteData.Values.get'
```

So I end up doing

```
public ActionResult TheAction(string target_name) { ViewBag.target_name = target_name; return View(); }
```

which appears to be very wrong (because it seems stupid)

How do I access target_name in my view?

Comment: Is route "ctrl" placed above default route definition in global.asax? And how do you exacly try to call RouteData.Values in cshtml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get at the RouteData in your view you need to get it through the ViewContext.

```
ViewContext.RouteData.Values["target_name"]
```

Comment: Why couldn't any of the pages mention or use ViewContext in their example. Thanks that solved it